# Is it possible to create a tray applet with Qt?

Tags: qt, system-tray, tray, systray

I want to make a tray applet using Qt that will use an output from a bash script to show some basic info. Is that possible to do in Qt? I wasn't able to find any tutorial via google, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the [System Tray Icon Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-systray-example.html)?

(Please note that the term "applet" is something different than the term "tray icon". The former is used for something more than just an icon and in most cases (which is very system dependent) a background process and placed by the user into the tray bar, where your tray icon is put in the system tray bar by a foreground application.)

Comment: Thank you for the link a lot. Yes, I understand. Yes I would like it to be something of a tray icon, that accepts the output from bash script, which is cron dependent job. This is how I visualize it at least. A standalone applet is a more difficult task, I guess. I don't have any experience with making gui apps, which demand good knowledge of python at least.